# How to use tensorflow 2.10 with large dataset?

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, large-data

I am using a large dataset to train on tensorflow 2.10.
But I am getting error as GPU memory exhausted.
My thought was that using `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` should resolve the problem. But the problem persists with using `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`.

```
 File d:\scripts\train.py:69
    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))

  File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py:814 in from_tensor_slices
    return TensorSliceDataset(tensors, name=name)

  File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py:4708 in __init__
    element = structure.normalize_element(element)

  File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\util\structure.py:126 in normalize_element
    ops.convert_to_tensor(t, name="component_%d" % i, dtype=dtype))

  File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\profiler\trace.py:183 in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:1638 in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)

  File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_conversion_registry.py:48 in _default_conversion_function
    return constant_op.constant(value, dtype, name=name)

  File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:267 in constant
    return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,

  File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:279 in _constant_impl
    return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)

  File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:304 in _constant_eager_impl
    t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)

  File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:102 in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)

InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.
```

below is my tensorflow 2.10 implementation-

Can someone please let me know what I am missing here.

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

import joblib
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, LSTM, multiply, concatenate, Activation, Masking, Reshape
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, BatchNormalization, GlobalAveragePooling1D, Permute, Dropout

def squeeze_excite_block(input):
    filters = input.shape[-1]
    se = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(input)
    se = Reshape((1, filters))(se)
    se = Dense(filters // 16,  activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', use_bias=False)(se)
    se = Dense(filters, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='he_normal', use_bias=False)(se)
    se = multiply([input, se])
    return se

def generate_model(lstm_size, conv_size, num_variables, num_timesteps):
    ip = Input(shape=(num_timesteps, num_variables))

    x = Masking()(ip)
    x = LSTM(lstm_size)(x)

    y = Masking()(ip)
    y = Conv1D(conv_size, 8, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(y)
    y = BatchNormalization()(y)
    y = Activation('elu')(y)
    y = squeeze_excite_block(y)

    y = Conv1D(conv_size*2, 5, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(y)
    y = BatchNormalization()(y)
    y = Activation('elu')(y)
    y = squeeze_excite_block(y)

    y = Conv1D(conv_size, 3, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(y)
    y = BatchNormalization()(y)
    y = Activation('elu')(y)

    y = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(y)

    x = concatenate([x, y])
    out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

    model = Model(ip, out)
    model.summary()

    return model

X_train = joblib.load("X_train.pkl")
y_train = joblib.load("y_train.pkl")
X_test = joblib.load("X_test.pkl")
y_test = joblib.load("y_test.pkl")

num_variables=8
num_timesteps=20
lstm_size=8
conv_size = 32
learning_rate = 0.001
num_epochs=100
model = generate_model(lstm_size, conv_size, num_variables, num_timesteps)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=2)])
checkpoint_filepath = str(lstm_size)+'_'+str(conv_size)+'_best_model.h5'

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, y_test))

model_checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_filepath, save_best_only=True, monitor='val_f1_score',\
                    mode='max', save_weights_only=True, verbose=1)
early_stopping_callback = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_f1_score', mode='max', patience=5,\
                    verbose=1, restore_best_weights=True)

history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=num_epochs, callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback, early_stopping_callback])
```